# "Unfavourable" execution plan with Postgres and PostGIS

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have the following database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE public.sgclasstab_id67
( 
    oid bigint NOT NULL,
    att_1113 bigint,
    att_1114 bigint,
    att_1115 character varying(500),
    att_1116 character varying(2000),
    att_1578 double precision,
    CONSTRAINT sgclasstab_id67_pkey PRIMARY KEY (oid)
)

CREATE TABLE public.sgclasstab_id68
(
    oid bigint NOT NULL,
    att_1119 bigint,
    att_1139 bigint,
    att_1496 character varying(2000),
    CONSTRAINT sgclasstab_id68_pkey PRIMARY KEY (oid)
)

CREATE TABLE public.sggeofacelist
(
    oid bigint NOT NULL,
    meanid smallint,
    numofislands smallint DEFAULT 0,
    compound smallint DEFAULT 0,
    extra character varying(512),
    crs bigint DEFAULT (-1),
    crsapp bigint DEFAULT (-1),
    version bigint DEFAULT 0,
    feature geometry,
    CONSTRAINT sggeofacelist_pkey PRIMARY KEY (oid),
    CONSTRAINT enforce_dims_feature CHECK (st_ndims(feature) = 3),
    CONSTRAINT enforce_srid_feature CHECK (st_srid(feature) = 0)
)

CREATE TABLE public.sggeopointlist
(
    oid bigint NOT NULL,
    angle double precision,
    meanid smallint,
    crs bigint DEFAULT (-1),
    crsapp bigint DEFAULT (-1),
    origx double precision,
    origy double precision,
    feature geometry,
    CONSTRAINT sggeopointlist_pkey PRIMARY KEY (oid),
    CONSTRAINT enforce_dims_feature CHECK (st_ndims(feature) = 3),
    CONSTRAINT enforce_srid_feature CHECK (st_srid(feature) = 0)
)
```

The column sgclasstab_id67.att_1114 references geometries in the table sggeofacelist, which contains only polygons, sgclasstab_id68.att_1139 references geometries in the table sggeopointlist, which contains only point geometries. Both tables can contain hundred thousands of geometries, only a small percentage of them being related to the above tables. All geometries use GIST indexes.

Now, when I run the following query

```
UPDATE sgclasstab_id68 SET att_1496 = (
    SELECT t3943814704643.att_1115 
    FROM sgclasstab_id67 t3943814704643, sggeofacelist t3943863539361, sgclasstab_id68 t3943875447103, sggeopointlist t3943875522916 
    WHERE ((t3943814704643.att_1114=t3943863539361.oid )) 
        AND ((t3943875447103.att_1139=t3943875522916.oid )) 
        AND ((t3943863539361.feature && (t3943875522916.feature) AND ST_Intersects(t3943863539361.feature,(t3943875522916.feature)))) 
        AND (t3943863539361.oid=t3943814704643.att_1114)  
        AND sgclasstab_id68.oid = t3943875447103.oid 
    LIMIT 1
)
```

it literally runs forever (i cancelled it after 4 days). This is to no surprise, looking at the execution plan:

```
Update on sgclasstab_id68  (cost=0.00..1076.63 rows=100 width=736)
  ->  Seq Scan on sgclasstab_id68  (cost=0.00..1076.63 rows=100 width=736)
        SubPlan 1
          ->  Limit  (cost=0.70..10.48 rows=1 width=516)
                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.70..10.48 rows=1 width=516)
                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.55..10.18 rows=1 width=524)
                            ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.29..9.33 rows=1 width=5482)
                                  ->  Seq Scan on sgclasstab_id67 t3943814704643  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=524)
                                  ->  Index Scan using sggeofacelist_pkey on sggeofacelist t3943863539361  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=4974)
                                        Index Cond: (oid = t3943814704643.att_1114)
                            ->  Index Scan using sggeopointlist_idx on sggeopointlist t3943875522916  (cost=0.27..0.84 rows=1 width=48)
                                  Index Cond: ((t3943863539361.feature && feature) AND (t3943863539361.feature && feature))
                                  Filter: _st_intersects(t3943863539361.feature, feature)
                      ->  Index Scan using sgclasstab_id68a1139_idx on sgclasstab_id68 t3943875447103  (cost=0.14..0.29 rows=1 width=8)
                            Index Cond: (att_1139 = t3943875522916.oid)
                            Filter: (sgclasstab_id68.oid = oid)
```

If i didn't misread anything here, Postgres first performs the intersection and then rules out all irrelevant geometries that are not referenced by objects from sgclasstab_id68.

Wouldn't it be much more performant to swap those two operations or did I do something in this query to make this option unavailable? If no, is there a way to force Postgres to reconsider?

PostgreSQL 9.3, PostGIS 2.1.1 r12113.

Thanks in advance (and sorry for the hard-to-read query, it's autogenerated).

Comment: Please use aliases for tables in your query. It's unreadable.

Comment: I think you mean don't use aliases like t3943863539361 don't you :D

Comment: You don't actually need the && bounding box check, as it is implied by ST_Intersects. If you remove that, and rename t3943863539361 something like poly, etc, it will be easier to debug. However, first thoughts are that your spatial indexes are not being used, as there is no index scan using <geom index name> in explain output.

Comment: BTW the `AND sgclasstab_id68.oid = t3943875447103.oid` compares a column with itself, maybe a typo by the "framework" ? (resulting in a carthesian product)

Comment: Aha, this appears to be the target table without an alias. Sorry ...

Comment: The result of the select query is used as input for the update query, `sgclasstab_id68.oid = t3943875447103.oid` is used to establish a mapping between the updated instance of sgclasstab_id68 and the instance in the select statement, so Postgres knows where to put which result.

Comment: No, it refers to the inner classtab_id68 reference. See my answer.

Comment: @JohnBarça Oh, you're right. But it's still unreadable without aliases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking joop's answers into account, i came up with the following cleaned up and modified version of my first statement

```
UPDATE sgclasstab_id68 SET att_1496 = (
    SELECT sgclasstab_id67.att_1115 
    FROM sgclasstab_id67, sggeofacelist, sggeopointlist 
    WHERE ((sgclasstab_id67.att_1114=sggeofacelist.oid )) 
        AND ((sgclasstab_id68.att_1139=sggeopointlist.oid )) 
        AND (ST_Intersects(sggeofacelist.feature,(sggeopointlist.feature))) 
        AND (sggeofacelist.oid=sgclasstab_id67.att_1114)  
)
```

This yields the following execution plan

```
Update on sgclasstab_id68  (cost=0.00..1074.13 rows=100 width=736)
  ->  Seq Scan on sgclasstab_id68  (cost=0.00..1074.13 rows=100 width=736)
        SubPlan 1
          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.55..10.18 rows=1 width=516)
                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.29..9.33 rows=1 width=5482)
                      ->  Seq Scan on sgclasstab_id67  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=524)
                      ->  Index Scan using sggeofacelist_pkey on sggeofacelist  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=4974)
                            Index Cond: (oid = sgclasstab_id67.att_1114)
                ->  Index Scan using sggeopointlist_idx on sggeopointlist  (cost=0.27..0.84 rows=1 width=40)
                      Index Cond: (sggeofacelist.feature && feature)
                      Filter: ((sgclasstab_id68.att_1139 = oid) AND _st_intersects(sggeofacelist.feature, feature))
```

The results seem to be identical and the first tests already imply that it is faster by orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

[not an answer]
FYI: the cleaned-up query(hope I didn't make any misstakes):

```
UPDATE sgclasstab_id68 dst
SET att_1496 = (
    SELECT cla.att_1115
    FROM sgclasstab_id67 cla 
    JOIN sggeofacelist fac ON cla.att_1114 = fac.oid AND fac.oid = cla.att_1114
    JOIN sggeopointlist pnt ON fac.feature && (pnt.feature) AND ST_Intersects(fac.feature, pnt.feature)
    JOIN sgclasstab_id68 cla2 ON cla2.att_1139 = pnt.oid
    WHERE 1=1
        AND dst.oid = cla2.oid
        -- AND cla2.oid = cla2.oid
    LIMIT 1 
    )
    ;
```

[ANSWER]
It appears that the unaliased cla2 (classtab_id68) reference refers to the **inner** query, and not to the destination table in the outer UPDATE statement. So all the `classtab_id68` will be updated with the same value. Also there is a lack of FK constraints/indexes for the joined columns.

---

UPDATE: on second thought the table reference `JOIN sgclasstab_id68 cla2` is not necessary; it refers to the same row as the target row, so the query can be further reduced to:

```
UPDATE sgclasstab_id68 dst
SET att_1496 = (
    SELECT c67.att_1115 
    FROM sgclasstab_id67 c67 
    JOIN sggeofacelist fl ON c67.att_1114 = fl.oid AND fl.oid = c67.att_1114
    JOIN sggeopointlist pnt ON (fl.feature && pnt.feature) AND ST_Intersects(fl.feature, pnt.feature)
    WHERE dst.att_1139 = pnt.oid 
    LIMIT 1
    )
        ;
```

[but there still is a need for proper FKs/indexes.]

---

Addendum: the `LIMIT 1` in the subquery (without an order by) is suspect, too. You'll want your update to be *kind of* deterministic, at least. This subquery just picks one random row from the result set (if there are more than one) and assigns that to the destination table. Does not seem logical; at least not to me.

---

Finally you don't really need the scalar(?) subquery, but can use of the normal `UPDATE` syntax instead (I also removed the boundingbox join, which is already implied by the `ST_intersects()` join:

```
UPDATE sgclasstab_id68 dst
SET att_1496 = c67.att_1115 
FROM sgclasstab_id67 c67    
JOIN sggeofacelist fl ON c67.att_1114 = fl.oid AND fl.oid = c67.att_1114
JOIN sggeopointlist pnt ON ST_Intersects(fl.feature, pnt.feature)
WHERE dst.att_1139 = pnt.oid    
    ;
```

Comment: No, I replaced the aliases by readable ones (cla2 in this case). The final join joins the inner classtab_id68 table with itself, not with the outer one.

Comment: Thanks, I can confirm that this query is functionally identical (and much more readable), but I don't really understand the answer. Removing the alias `dst` does not change the functionality for me. I believe the referencing was correct before since it worked in hundreds of other cases.

Comment: Thanks Joop, i believe you did it! I had do do a small change to your last statement but you found the issue. As soon as I'm able to post answers here, I'll provide a detailed solution. ps. Sorry I can't vote you up, but that requires 15 reputation at least.

Answer (score 0):

`NOT an answer, just an attempt to clarify the question with formatting (taken from joop)`. Does this still do what you want, and if so, what is the output of explain now?

```
UPDATE sgclasstab_id68 dst
    SET att_1496 = (
       SELECT cla.att_1115
    FROM sgclasstab_id67 cla 
       JOIN sggeofacelist fac ON cla.att_1114 = fac.oid AND fac.oid = cla.att_1114        
       JOIN sgclasstab_id68 cla2 ON cla2.att_1139 = pnt.oid
    WHERE  dst.oid = cla2.oid
       AND ST_Intersects(fac.feature, pnt.feature)       
  );
```

Comment: I was referring to the ANSWER part below the code. Anyway, my reputation doesn't allow me to post anything but comments for the next 7 hours, but the EXPLAIN looks like the prior one without the limit clause. BTW. I added `JOIN sggeopointlist pnt ON fac.feature && (pnt.feature)`, to reference the point geometries, is that ok?

Comment: The && is unnecessary, it just means bounding box compare, which is handled automatically as part of ST_Intersects. This is why I put AND ST_Intersects(fac.feature, pnt.feature)  in the where, as I think it is clearer than putting it as a join clause. Does that make sense? +1 for a good question, but you'll probably need another couple before you can do anything useful.

Comment: @JohnBarça FYI: There was a typo in my first rewrite. (these aliases are killing me ;-)

Comment: @joop, no kidding, these ORM generated queries are terrible to read. Have you updated your answer?

Comment: Yes I made a misstake somewhere between cl1 and cl2, IIRC. The part below the `UPDATE` is now correct (I guess) To be sure: start with the original and do some search&replace (and other) transformations.My conclusion is that cl2 reference can be completely removed (the reference to the outer table was intended) wash, rinse, repeat... ;-[